# Produce a value in one cell, if another cell contains a specific text in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that has 1000 rows. I would like to insert certain values in a specific column if another column contains a certain text string.

```
name    value
hello
ok
sure
hello
```

[image]

Where ever there is the word, hello, I would like 33
for ok, I'd like 32
for sure, I'd like 34

Doing:

```
=IF(B5=$B$4,33,"")
```

This works, but how would I include the other criteria? The formula keeps saying I have too many arguments.

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How you defining these values. Which value for which words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value is assigned liked `hello=33`, `ok=32`, `sure=34` then you can use below formula.

```
=INDEX({33,32,34},,MATCH(A2,{"hello","ok","sure"},0))
```

With `Excel365` you can use `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,{"hello","ok","sure"},{33,32,34})
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @Lynn Glad to know!